# Arguments to JavaScript Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, anonymous-function

```
for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++)
{
    myclass.foo({'arg1':somearray[i][0]}, function()
    {
        console.log(somearray[i][0]);
    });
}
```

How do I pass somearray or one of its indexes into the anonymous function ?
somearray is already in the global scope, but I still get **somearray[i] is undefined**

Comment: this is a common problem - see all related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `i` in the anonymous function captures the *variable* `i`, not its *value*.  By the end of the loop, `i` is equal to `somearray.length`, so when you invoke the function it tries to access an non-existing element array.

You can fix this by making a function-constructing function that captures the variable's value:

```
function makeFunc(j) { return function() { console.log(somearray[j][0]); } }

for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++)
{
    myclass.foo({'arg1':somearray[i][0]}, makeFunc(i));
}
```

`makeFunc`'s argument could have been named `i`, but I called it `j` to show that it's a different variable than the one used in the loop.

Comment: +1 for giving a good explanation of the problem, as well as providing a solution!

Comment: I got your point. Thanks. But I just cant figure out how to call makeFunc.

Comment: Awesome ! I got my problem solved. This is totally a new thing for me in JavaScript !

Answer (score 10):

How about a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++) {
    var val = somearray[i][0];
    myclass.foo({'arg1': val}, function(v) {
      return function() {console.log(v) };
    }(val) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++)

{
    myclass.foo({'arg1':somearray[i][0]}, function(somearray)
    {
        console.log(somearray[i][0]);
    });
}
```

And then in method foo call anonymous function with param.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables values to annoymous function by using callback,
something like

```
myclass.foo(function(variable){
      return function(){
        console.log(variable);
      }
    })(variableValue);
);
```

check this post: https://shahpritesh.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/javascript-function-in-loop-passing-dynamic-variable-value/

Answer (score -2):

All the functions/methods can be used as callbacks only. When you call the callback function you pass variables to it.

```
var myclass = {
  foo: function(params, callback){
    // do some stuff
    callback(variable1, variable1, variableN);
  }
}
```