# Get iterator index into a onmousedown function

Tags: javascript, html, loops, onmousedown

I am trying to do a seemingly trivial thing, but I cant figure this out. I am iterating over items found by the `document.getElementByClassName` method. I am doing so with indices so I can keep track of some stuff, and I need that index inside the `onmousedown` events for that specific element, however I can't figure out to do so.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");

    for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        items[i].onmousedown=function(){
            //This does not work:
            var index = i; //I need the i variable from the loop above in here.
            console.log(index);
            this.innerHTML = doSomeWorkWith(index);
        };  

    }
```

Anyone know how to do this? I have thought of adding it to the element itself so I can access a variable there, but I would prefere not to as it would clutter the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create the handler functions on the fly, using another function. That can easily be done using immediately invoced function expressions (IIFEs). That way, you'll get the `i` to be evaluated when defining the handler, not when executing it.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    items[i].onmousedown = (function (index) {
        return function () {
            console.log(index);
            this.innerHTML = doSomeWorkWith(index);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Basically, I'm not directly assigning a function to `onmousedown`, but creating one on the fly that has the value of `i` hardcoded.
To create that handler function, I'm using another function, that I immediately (in-place) invoke after defining it, without ever assigning a name. (Of course I just could create that function in global scope and us it here, but as I don't need it anywhere else, why should I?)

[Edit]: To use the event inside that function, use

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    items[i].onmousedown = (function (index) {
        return function (event) {
            this.innerHTML = doSomeWorkWith(index);
            // do something with "event" here
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted the mouse event parameter that is normally passed in to this function, how would I do that?

Comment: Let the inner function (the one that has no parameter now) take it. Inside that function, use it as you always would.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep your indexes in closure, something as

```
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    (function(index){
        ...do anithing
    })(i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical problem, the anonymous function captures the variable and not its value, so when it is indeed called, the current value is not correct.

See this link for more information : [Arguments to JavaScript Anonymous Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023874/arguments-to-javascript-anonymous-function)